# ListView inside nested TabHost

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost

I have 4 tabs at the bottom of the screen.
the second tab opens an activity which is having 3-7 tabs of its own.
all these tabs shows different lists.

I am able to navigate to list, but list view hides the bottom tabs.

How can I add listview inside tabhost child of another tabhost ?
I don't want any tab to hide.[image: Required screen design]

Comment: Something tells me that your layout is too complicated...

Answer (score 0):

make layout_marginBottom in your listView according your layout